# IIS Manager IIS6 Rights Management on Windows Server 2003

Tags: security, iis, iis-6, dedicated-hosting, iis-manager

We are using a dedicated hosting provider to host several of our public websites.  There are two development teams/divisions within our company who each maintain public websites on these same servers.  Is there a way through ACLs or some sort of rights management (e.g. individual logins) that I would only be able to see and maintain only my public sites and the other development team could only see and maintain their sites?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Sure - File ACLS is probably the way to go, if you've got access to the server.

You can set up a directory called Site1 and ACL Change rights to a local Group "LG-Site1" with the appropriate users, and directory Site2 with change rights for group "LG-Site2".

You do state that you want to only see your site, not the other site - the challenge with this is that if you are logging in to the server, you probably have admin rights, or at least rights up to the point where anything you do to lock yourself out of the Site2 directory can be reversed - either by temporarily granting your self rights or adding your self to LG-Site2.  Not necessarily a show stopper, but certainly a consideration.

You can also set up FTP so that each dev team can publish to their directory, but not get in to the other.

Comment: Yep - agreed. It's been a while since I've used IIS6 (and on a hosting provider) but that does sound right.